# 401 Unathorized. FreePBX

Tags: linux, freebsd, asterisk, freepbx

```
    [2017-03-01 15:10:40] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c: Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 212.86.230.1:58318:
OPTIONS sip:7838@212.86.230.1:58318;ob SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 195.54.162.238:5160;branch=z9hG4bK1da64c3b;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "Unknown" <sip:Unknown@195.54.162.238:5160>;tag=as189d33ee
To: <sip:7838@212.86.230.1:58318;ob>
Contact: <sip:Unknown@195.54.162.238:5160>
Call-ID: 4c39f58c3de5f00348b3033d73ea2593@195.54.162.238:5160
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
User-Agent: FPBX-13.0.151(13.12.1)
Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 13:10:40 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0


---
[2017-03-01 15:10:40] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c:
<--- SIP read from UDP:212.86.230.1:58318 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 195.54.162.238:5160;rport=5160;received=195.54.162.238;branch=z9hG4bK1da64c3b
Call-ID: 4c39f58c3de5f00348b3033d73ea2593@195.54.162.238:5160
From: "Unknown" <sip:Unknown@195.54.162.238>;tag=as189d33ee
To: <sip:7838@212.86.230.1;ob>;tag=z9hG4bK1da64c3b
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Accept: application/sdp, application/pidf+xml, application/xpidf+xml, application/simple-message-summary, message/sipfrag;version=2.0, application/im-iscomposing+xml, text/plain
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Allow-Events: presence, message-summary, refer
User-Agent: CSipSimple_hct6580_weg_c_m-23/r2457
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 286

v=0
o=- 3697369839 3697369839 IN IP4 192.168.1.130
s=pjmedia
t=0 0
m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP 99 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.130
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:99 SILK/24000
a=fmtp:99 useinbandfec=0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
<------------->
[2017-03-01 15:10:40] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c: --- (13 headers 13 lines) ---
[2017-03-01 15:10:40] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c: Really destroying SIP dialog '4c39f58c3de5f00348b3033d73ea2593@195.54.162.238:5160' Method: OPTIONS
[2017-03-01 15:11:00] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c:
<--- SIP read from UDP:212.86.230.1:58318 --->

<------------->
[2017-03-01 15:11:40] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c: Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 212.86.230.1:58318:
OPTIONS sip:7838@212.86.230.1:58318;ob SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 195.54.162.238:5160;branch=z9hG4bK3cd998e6;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "Unknown" <sip:Unknown@195.54.162.238:5160>;tag=as1527e489
To: <sip:7838@212.86.230.1:58318;ob>
Contact: <sip:Unknown@195.54.162.238:5160>
Call-ID: 682eaed336beb39a71c0b56e151dd7b4@195.54.162.238:5160
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
User-Agent: FPBX-13.0.151(13.12.1)
Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 13:11:40 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0


---
[2017-03-01 15:11:41] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c:
<--- SIP read from UDP:212.86.230.1:58318 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 195.54.162.238:5160;rport=5160;received=195.54.162.238;branch=z9hG4bK3cd998e6
Call-ID: 682eaed336beb39a71c0b56e151dd7b4@195.54.162.238:5160
From: "Unknown" <sip:Unknown@195.54.162.238>;tag=as1527e489
To: <sip:7838@212.86.230.1;ob>;tag=z9hG4bK3cd998e6
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Accept: application/sdp, application/pidf+xml, application/xpidf+xml, application/simple-message-summary, message/sipfrag;version=2.0, application/im-iscomposing+xml, text/plain
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Allow-Events: presence, message-summary, refer
User-Agent: CSipSimple_hct6580_weg_c_m-23/r2457
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 286

v=0
o=- 3697369899 3697369899 IN IP4 192.168.1.130
s=pjmedia
t=0 0
m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP 99 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.130
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:99 SILK/24000
a=fmtp:99 useinbandfec=0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
<------------->
[2017-03-01 15:11:41] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c: --- (13 headers 13 lines) ---
[2017-03-01 15:11:41] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c: Really destroying SIP dialog '682eaed336beb39a71c0b56e151dd7b4@195.54.162.238:5160' Method: OPTIONS
[2017-03-01 15:11:42] NOTICE[1953] chan_sip.c: -- Re-registration for 170208100@208.89.105.9
[2017-03-01 15:11:42] NOTICE[1953] chan_sip.c: Outbound Registration: Expiry for 208.89.105.9 is 120 sec (Scheduling reregistration in 105 s)
[2017-03-01 15:12:21] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c:
<--- SIP read from UDP:212.86.230.1:58318 --->

<------------->
[2017-03-01 15:12:41] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c: Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 212.86.230.1:58318:
OPTIONS sip:7838@212.86.230.1:58318;ob SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 195.54.162.238:5160;branch=z9hG4bK2b090cc8;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "Unknown" <sip:Unknown@195.54.162.238:5160>;tag=as698793bc
To: <sip:7838@212.86.230.1:58318;ob>
Contact: <sip:Unknown@195.54.162.238:5160>
Call-ID: 7a35069f0003f82e56789902484928e8@195.54.162.238:5160
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
User-Agent: FPBX-13.0.151(13.12.1)
Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 13:12:41 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0


---
[2017-03-01 15:12:41] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c:
<--- SIP read from UDP:212.86.230.1:58318 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 195.54.162.238:5160;rport=5160;received=195.54.162.238;branch=z9hG4bK2b090cc8
Call-ID: 7a35069f0003f82e56789902484928e8@195.54.162.238:5160
From: "Unknown" <sip:Unknown@195.54.162.238>;tag=as698793bc
To: <sip:7838@212.86.230.1;ob>;tag=z9hG4bK2b090cc8
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Accept: application/sdp, application/pidf+xml, application/xpidf+xml, application/simple-message-summary, message/sipfrag;version=2.0, application/im-iscomposing+xml, text/plain
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Allow-Events: presence, message-summary, refer
User-Agent: CSipSimple_hct6580_weg_c_m-23/r2457
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 286

v=0
o=- 3697369960 3697369960 IN IP4 192.168.1.130
s=pjmedia
t=0 0
m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP 99 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.130
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:99 SILK/24000
a=fmtp:99 useinbandfec=0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
<------------->
[2017-03-01 15:12:41] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c: --- (13 headers 13 lines) ---
[2017-03-01 15:12:41] VERBOSE[1953] chan_sip.c: Really destroying SIP dialog '7a35069f0003f82e56789902484928e8@195.54.162.238:5160' Method: OPTIONS
[2017-03-01 15:12:52] NOTICE[11088] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'SUBSCRIBE' from '<sip:7838@195.54.162.238>' failed for '212.86.230.1:58318' (callid: Wi2IT3gm3iy1R0O6jCL9qSfGlWkvmwCR) - No matching endpoint found
[2017-03-01 15:12:52] NOTICE[11088] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'SUBSCRIBE' from '<sip:7838@195.54.162.238>' failed for '212.86.230.1:58318' (callid: Wi2IT3gm3iy1R0O6jCL9qSfGlWkvmwCR) - No matching endpoint found
[2017-03-01 15:12:52] NOTICE[11088] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'SUBSCRIBE' from '<sip:7838@195.54.162.238>' failed for '212.86.230.1:58318' (callid: Wi2IT3gm3iy1R0O6jCL9qSfGlWkvmwCR) - Failed to authenticate
[2017-03-01 15:13:17] NOTICE[11088] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'INVITE' from '<sip:7838@195.54.162.238>' failed for '212.86.230.1:58318' (callid: vhOxOhh2DCdD0bsYo9.cQrFb.HEZA8cx) - No matching endpoint found
[2017-03-01 15:13:17] NOTICE[11088] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'INVITE' from '<sip:7838@195.54.162.238>' failed for '212.86.230.1:58318' (callid: vhOxOhh2DCdD0bsYo9.cQrFb.HEZA8cx) - No matching endpoint found
[2017-03-01 15:13:17] NOTICE[11088] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'INVITE' from '<sip:7838@195.54.162.238>' failed for '212.86.230.1:58318' (callid: vhOxOhh2DCdD0bsYo9.cQrFb.HEZA8cx) - Failed to authenticate
```

Данные лог файла Выше. Подключаюсь телефоном нормально к Asterisk. Но при вызове выкидывает ошибку: 401 Unathorized

Comment: если с другими логинами нормально, то сравните их настройки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin на всех тоже самое